# Efficient way to do the filter using loadash or any other library?

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter

I am filtering array whenever checkboxes are checked. There are totally 7 checkboxe each is associated with an object.

here is my code,

```
 if (this.deliveryConcession[0].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.deliveryconcession.readytoship === this.deliveryConcession[0].checked);
        }
        if (this.deliveryConcession[1].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.deliveryconcession.instantdownload === this.deliveryConcession[1].checked);
        }
        if (this.deliveryConcession[2].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.deliveryconcession.unespecifiedshipment === this.deliveryConcession[2].checked);
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[0].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.parking === this.seatConcession[0].checked);
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[1].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.restrictedview === this.seatConcession[1].checked);
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[2].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.wheelchair === this.seatConcession[2].checked);
        }
        if (this.seatConcession[3].checked) {
            this.allItems = this.allItems.filter(fil => fil.seatingConcession.alcoholFree === this.seatConcession[3].checked);
        }
```

here is my objects for filter,

```
  seatConcession = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Parking pass included', checked: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'Unrestricted view', checked: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'Wheel chair accessible', checked: false },
        { id: 4, name: 'Without age restrictions', checked: false }
    ];
    deliveryConcession = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Ready to ship(paper)', checked: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'Instant download(e-ticket)', checked: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'Unspecified shipment(paper)', checked: false }
    ];
```

how can i improve the above with simple loadash filter or another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
let keys = [
  ["readytoship", "deliveryConcession"],
  ["instantdownload", "deliveryConcession"],
  /* and so on, make sure to order */
];

this.allItems.filter(item => {
  return keys.every((arr, i) => {
    let [k, attr] = arr;
    return item[attr][k] === this[attr][i].checked;
  });
});
```

You will need to order the keys array appropriately. But now it's a two-liner. Other than `let` and the arrow functions this is all valid ES 5, no lodash required.

### EDIT

Since you still haven't actually posted the relevant code this is still something of a stab in the dark, but taking your sample input of

```
seatConcession = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Parking pass included', checked: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'Unrestricted view', checked: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'Wheel chair accessible', checked: false },
        { id: 4, name: 'Without age restrictions', checked: false }
];
deliveryConcession = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Ready to ship(paper)', checked: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'Instant download(e-ticket)', checked: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'Unspecified shipment(paper)', checked: false }
];
```

And assuming you have a list of which checkboxes are checked that is ordered in the same order as the objects like so

```
let checked = [true, false, true, true, false /* etc */];
```

You want to do something like this:

```
let filtered = seatConcessions
  .concat(deliveryConcession)
  .filter((obj, i) => checked[i]);
```

You will have to adapt this to your specific case (again, since the sample input you put up is different than the code you wrote), but is a pattern for doing this in general.

Comment: what about deliveryconcession?

Comment: @faceturn define "not working". Expected output for sample input would be helpful here.

Comment: i have updated the question with the objects, please have a look

Comment: I think OP is asking a better solution for the `this.allItems.filter...` portion of the code (which I believe is too specific to generilize it)

Comment: @vassiliskrikonis is the above way bad?

Comment: can you post your `allItems`?

Comment: @JaredSmith actually i need to filter allitems based on the checked value of the checkbox